# Database transfer from Heroku to Digital Ocean

Tags: postgresql, heroku, digital-ocean

I'm currently in the process of switching my cloud server from Heroku to Digital Ocean. However is there a way to migrate the database from the heroku server to the digital ocean one? I use postgresql for my database

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm in the same situation.

Comment: @AdonesPitogo Just posted one if still interested.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you already got a solution, but in case you didn’t, I’ll provide a simple guide on how I did it. I am going to assume that you have already created a postgres database on digitalocean. Also you need navigate to your project directory and log in to heroku using the heroku cli. And, you need to have postgresql installed or a `psql` client. Installing postgresql would do it as it comes with `psql`.

##### Step 1: Create a backup and download the backup from heroku postgres

```
heroku pg:backups:capture --app <app_name>
heroku pg:backups:download --app <app_name>
```

The first command will create a backup of your database and the second command will download it to your current directory, its a `.dump` file. If you would like to read more, [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) is an article.

##### Step 2:  Connect to your remote (digital ocean’s) database using `psql`

Before you can do this, you need to go and add your machine you are connecting from to the list of database’s **list of trusted sources**, If you don’t, you’ll get a `Connection Timed Out error`. That’s because the database’s firewall doesn’t allow you to connect to the database from your local machine or resource (for security reasons).

##### Step 3: Import the Database

```
pg_restore -d "postgresql://<database_username>:<database_password>@<host>:<port>/<database>?sslmode=require" --jobs 4 -c "/path/to/dump_file.dump"
```

This will import your database from your dump file. Just substitute the variables will your connection parameters that you get from your dashboard. If you would like to read more, [here](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/databases/postgresql/how-to/import-databases/) is another article for this step.

Another thing to make clear is, sometimes, you will see some harmless error messages when running this command, but it will push through anyway. To learn more about `pg_restore` read [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) article.

And that’s it, your database has been migrated. Now, can you confirm it worked?, well, as for me, I used `pgAdmin` to connect to the remote database and I saw the tables and data as expected.
Hope this helps anyone with the same problem :)